# Does anyone know a working OCR (PHP)?

Tags: php, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I implement OCR on a website using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170271/how-can-i-implement-ocr-on-a-website-using-php)

Ive been looking for a working OCR class (must be PHP) for almost 3 days.

Anyone knows a working OCR? please guide me if you have a OCR sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement OCR on a website using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170271/how-can-i-implement-ocr-on-a-website-using-php)

Comment: @Moshe, thanks for the link. Ive never seen that link. im checking it right now. thanks again for your help..

Comment: Are you writing a captcha solving spambot? :D

Comment: @mingos, no, i'm not. i'm not a spammer. trust me.

Comment: @Celin it's got nothing to do with that. Stackoverflow has a standing policy of no duplicates.

Comment: @Moshe, you asked same question months ago. well, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Celin - I ended up not persuing that project. See this answer though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170271/how-can-i-implement-ocr-on-a-website-using-php/2170419#2170419, it looks decent:

Comment: @Celin: when someone says "trust me", it's a good reason NOT to trust him :D (just kidding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe anybody implemented any OCR solution in PHP.
OCR ( Optical Character Recognition ) is a very complex piece of Software and not anything PHP would be suited for to implement.

But for sure you can call an external OCR program from PHP.
So you should look for an OCR solution which can be used from command line.

Comment: thanks for answer. can i call an .exe program from php? well, ive got "ABBY screenshot reader", and it's converting image to text succesfully.

Comment: Sure, there are several functions for this, look here: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php  Just be careful if you use external input, calling programs on a server has some security related aspects.

Comment: You're not 100% right. You can use OCR web API with PHP, for example,  http://ocrsdk.com/producttour/programming-languages/ works with PHP, here are the codesamples: https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/PHP

Comment: I tend to agree with @Nikolay you could turn an OCR library into a PHP extension and that would be 100% done in PHP, imho ymmv.