# Converting an image to text via Javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I implement OCR on a website using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170271/how-can-i-implement-ocr-on-a-website-using-php)

Are there any scripts out there to convert an image containing text into plain text, preferably using Javscript or PHP? For example, take the image below:

[image: JPEG Image]

I would like this image to be converted to simply "ABCDEFGHIJK."

Comment: look up OCR (optical character recognition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is called Optical Character Recognition (OCR) and there are lots of libraries available for most languages.

- [Does anyone know a working OCR (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810330/does-anyone-know-a-working-ocr-php)
- [How can I implement OCR on a website using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170271/how-can-i-implement-ocr-on-a-website-using-php)

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would help you ..
php:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html